# Can I do this without iteration?

Tags: analysis

Here is a formula where $y$ and $z$ are known
$$
  x = \frac{y-0.04z}{0.27z}
$$
How would I work out $z$ when only $x$ and $y$ are known?

Comment: This is a math site, not a finance, excel, or statistics site. We have sites for those other topics. I'd suggest you use them

Comment: Thanks - which one do you suggest?

Comment: I'd go with Excel as your question has to do with a feature on that program :)

Comment: Thanks Zach.  I'm just excel to show the problem..   what I need is a math formula to work out the answer.

Comment: In that case the economics/statistics stack exchange does the trick. It does depend on the formula being wanted though.

Comment: I can post there as well, however I thought if I needed an equation, Maths was the best place...  is it not?

Comment: Not unless the equation is given beforehand, you want a derivation, or you need help solving it.

Comment: Question updated. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25176/discussion-between-sunil-and-zach466920).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x={{y-0.04 \cdot z} \over {0.27 \cdot z}}$$
Multiply the denominator to clear the fraction
$$\Rightarrow 0.27 \cdot x\cdot z=y-0.04 \cdot z$$
Put the z's on the same side
$$\Rightarrow 0.27 \cdot x\cdot z+0.04 \cdot z=y$$
Factor "out" the z
$$z \cdot (0.27\cdot x+0.04)=y$$
Divide to get z
$$z={{y} \over {0.27 \cdot x+.04}}$$
This is equivalent to
$$z={{100 \cdot y} \over {27\cdot x+4}}$$

Hopefully you can generalize this method. Also, for future reference, make sure to post your own attempt at solution with your question.

(Posted on mobile)

Comment: Awesome - Thank you - I learned something today.  I did find a small problem with the last step of the formala  z =  100y / 27x + 4 .. The result was not the same as the previous step :)  But Thanks anyway - this really  helped :)

Comment: Your welcome. To get the last formula, multiply both the top and bottom by 100.